# Scripts on UNC paths take very long to run

Tags: windows, windows-xp, scripting, unc

I have several scripts in UNC paths (from Windows batch files to PHP scripts). No matter how I run them (double click on explorer, my editor's run command menu or Windows command prompt) they take really long to start running (like 14 seconds). Once they get started they run normally. This doesn't happen if I run them from mapped drives.

I'm using Windows XP Professional SP3 inside an Active Directory domain and files are hosted in a Windows Server box (not sure about the version, it's an HP dedicated file server with bundled OS).

Why does it happen? Is there a way to speed up things while using UNC paths?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be something related to name resolution? Did you tried to put IP address instead of the hostname?

Comment: Good point! UNC paths with IP addresses do not experience such slowdown. Any clue about why Windows does not cache name resolution?

Comment: You have some issues in the name resolution. Check that every XP use the AD Domain controller as DNS server.

Comment: Networks settings come from DHCP, but the DNS server's IP address matches the domain controller. Perhaps it's the DNS server itself the one that's misconfigured...